# how to add button clicked Indicator to my Login button

Tags: flutter, button

I'm creating a login page using flutter. when user click login button user didn't realize did they click the button or not. how to add an indicator for button click "Login" in my code. appreciate your help on this.

```
  class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
      final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      String email = "";
      String password = "";
    
      Future LoginData() async {
        try {
          var response = await Dio().post(BASE_API+'user/Login',
              data: {"email": email, "password": password});
    
          if (response.data["message"] == "logged in successfully") {
            Get.snackbar("success", "logged in successfully");
            Get.to(HomeScreen());
    
          } else {
            Get.snackbar(
              "error",
              "No User Found",
              // backgroundColor: heartRed.withOpacity(0.8),
              // colorText: textWhite,
            );
          }
          print("res: $response");
        } catch (e) {
          Get.snackbar("Error", "Something went wrong.Please contact admin",
              backgroundColor: textWhite.withOpacity(0.5),
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: textGrey,
              colorText: textGrey,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.error_outline_outlined,
                color: heartRed,
                size: 30,
              ));
          print(e);
        }
  }

Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: ButtonM("Login"),
                        onTap: () async {
                          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
                            LoginData();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    )
```

Comment: are they in same class or different?

Comment: https://wilsonwilson.dev/articles/flutter-hover-effect-triggers-the-definitive-guide/

Comment: they are on same class

Comment: You are expecting button effect or loadingicon ?

Comment: expecting button effect

Answer (score 1):

You can use a container and `GestureDetector(child: YourTextWidget())`. It have a sligh pressed animation in it. And you can use Package `flutter_easyloading` to show loading icon. `EasyLoading.show(status: "Loading");` and to stop `EasyLoading.dismiss();` and to show result `EasyLoading.showSuccess("Logged In Successfull!");`.

Comment: can you please provide the full code details showing where I want to add those codes.

Comment: Yes Just one minute.